# What is the title of the anime with the "DESU" maid?

Tags: story-identification, anime, meme

I've been watching AMVs forever and I keep seeing this little maid pop up in them that's in a green dress with blue and red eyes or something like that. She keeps yelling "DESU!" all the time. I think it's even a meme now, but I missed the boat on this one. So please, what anime is the DESU maid from?

Comment: Have you tried KnowYourMeme.com?

Comment: Can you be any more specific? Maybe link an amv? "Desu" is an extremely common "cutsey" thing to say instead of pronouncing it "des".

Comment: @GorchestopherH: I don't think you need to be more specific, the question is rather obviously referring to _Rozen Maiden_.

Comment: @JoeWreschnig Made the comment before the answer. I don't really "know memes" and a "maid who says desu a lot" technically fits a lot of characters. Wasn't aware of this particular dual-eye colored one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Know Your Meme](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/desu) the character is Suiseiseki from [*Rozen Maiden*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rozen_Maiden) where she ends every sentence with "desu" (pronounced /desu̥/).

[image]

Comment: I know nothing of the Japanese language, lol. I'm just going off what I've researched.

Comment: @JoeWreschnig To English speakers, です sounds like "des" even though it's transliterated as "desu".  The "u" in す is nearly silent.  'Tho, based on Gorchestopher's comment on the question, perhaps this character does pronounce it as the full "desu"?

Answer (score -1):

The character Suiseiseki from the anime series Rozen Maiden ends every sentence with desu. Im assuming that is what your talking about.

Comment: All of this information is already in the pre-existing accepted answer above.  Your post contributes nothing.